# Azure pipelines - how does Azure Network Load Balancer Task work?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-load-balancer, azure-devops-pipelines

I am setting up a release pipeline and I wanted to use the Azure Network Load Balancer task to take instances out of the load balancer, but I wanted to know how it does it, i.e. does it drain connections or kill connections.

I am guessing that if it's removing the network interface it's just killing connections, can anyone tell me?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureNLBManagementV1/nlbtask.ts) on github, the connect action adds loadBalancerBackendAddressPools porperty (The reference to LoadBalancerBackendAddressPool resource). It is actually set by calling [Network Interfaces-Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkinterfaces/createorupdate) rest api.

```
if (action == "Connect") {
        taskinternal._writeLine(tl.loc("ConnectingVMtoLB", loadBalancerName));
        var lb = await nlbUtility.getLoadBalancer(SPN, endpointUrl, loadBalancerName, resourceGroupName);
        nicLbBackendPoolConfig = lb.properties.backendAddressPools;
}
else {
        taskinternal._writeLine(tl.loc("DisconnectingVMfromLB", loadBalancerName));
}
nicVm.properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties['loadBalancerBackendAddressPools'] = nicLbBackendPoolConfig;
var setNIStatus = await nlbUtility.setNetworkInterface(SPN, endpointUrl, nicVm, resourceGroupName);
```